# What is the best way to learn more about Roslyn Code Analyzers

Tags: c#, roslyn

Can the use of Code Analyzers be incorporated with the use of Code Contracts and Static checking?

- Is it a good idea to use both (can you use both?)
- or is it overkill and would using Code Analyzers be enough?
- Are there specific instances when using one over the other is better?

Answer (score 1):

I myself researched this a bit. There is some info online. I suggest that you start with MSDN here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt162308.aspx

Comment: Thanks @JonMeyers I read through that myself. It is the best place to start IMHO but I am looking for additional reading. :-)